# PHP sort text file (.txt) numerically

Tags: php, sorting, text-files

Thank you for taking the time to read this and I will appreciate every single response no mater the quality of content. :)

Using php, I'm trying to create a script which will numerically sort a text file (.txt) in ascending order (lowest to highest). Each entry within the text file is on a new line, therefore I'd like the lines to be numerically sorted. If possible, once it has been numerically sorted, I'd like the data to be written into another text file, titled "newtime.txt" within the same directory. Of course, if possible. ;)

The main part I'm struggling with is that the content within the text file isn't static (e.g. contain x number of lines/words etc.) Infact, it is automatically updated with several lines. Therefore, I'd like all the lines to be updated numerically.

The text file follows the structure:

```
2 aullah1
12 name
7 username
```

Of course, which is regularly updated with more lines. Will it be possible to numerically sort the lines? Also, I plan on using a Cron Job to repeat the script every 5 minutes. ;)

P.S. What will happen if there are two same numbers? Will it then go onto sorting out the data alphabetically?

All assistance is appreciated and I look forward to your replies; thank you. :) If I didn't explain anything clearly and/or you'd like me to explain in more detail, please reply. :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you are working with a reasonable number of lines (thousands, not millions) this should be sufficient. If you have very large files, you may run into memory issues using `file()`:

```
<?php

$data = file($file_path);
natsort($data);
file_put_contents($new_file_path, implode("\n", $data));
```

You could replace the single `file_put_contents` with a looped `fwrite()` for each element in $data.

`natsort()` will sort the numerics correctly (as opposed to `asort()` which will put 10 before 2). For matching numerics, it will sort as you expect, comparing the rest of the string.

[natsort()](https://www.php.net/natsort), [file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Comment: What are you going to do when there are 500 billion rows to sort?  In-memory solutions don't scale.

Use the dba_*() functions with qdbm.  Build your database, using the derived keys as keys and the original lines as values.  Construct your keys such that they sort in the order you need, then do a sequential scan on the database, outputting the values (the original lines) to a new, sorted file.  Then close and delete the database.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this easily by

Reading the file into an array:

```
$lines = file($path_to_file);
```

Sort the array:

```
natsort($lines);
```

Write the array back to a new file:

```
file_put_contents($path_to_new_file, implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));
```

Comment: The last line should be: `file_put_contents($path_to_new_file, implode(PHP_EOL, $lines));`

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$lines = file("time.txt");
natsort($lines);
file_put_contents("newtime.txt", implode("\n", $lines));
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is by far the fastest and most elegant solution that I have found, when I had the same problem.
If you're on Linux (with exec allowed in PHP configuration) you can do the following (provided you want to sort files numerically):

```
exec("sort -n " . $pathToOriginalFile . " > " . $pathToSortedFile);
```

Basically, execute bash command **sort** that sorts the lines in a file numerically.
If you want to keep the data in the original file do this:

```
exec("sort -n " . $pathToOriginalFile . " > " . $pathToSortedFile);
exec("rm " . $pathToOriginalFile);
exec("mv " . $pathToSortedFile . " " . $pathToOriginalFile);
```

If you want an alphabetical sort just exclude -n (--numeric-sort) option.

```
exec("sort " . $pathToOriginalFile . " > " . $pathToSortedFile);
```

For me the command took about 3 seconds to sort 10 million lines in the file on the server.

You can find more about sort here http://www.computerhope.com/unix/usort.htm

Hope it helps.

Comment: Maybe You know how to do that on Win? I have "unreasonable" amount of rows (avg 10-20 millions).

Comment: Uhm, why would you ever use Win server for PHP application? To be honest, have no idea how to do this on Win, but get over to Linux or OS X asap, for any kind of PHP work.

Comment: I've got temporary server on desktop machine at work. But surprisingly shuffle() for 10M records took about 5 secs :) Anyway thanks for answer :)